# Oracle Query to select separate alphabet+numbers and numbers after special character

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query in oracle where I have requirement  to separate alphabet+numbers and numbers after special character as 2 different columns

Eg.

**Colum Value is** 
ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900 
**Output Required** 
Column 1 : ABC 123,XYZ,PQR 444 
Column 2 : 78800,4666, 9900 

I **tried** following query:
select TRANSLATE('ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900 ','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789#','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') from dual.

**Output** is "ABC ,XYZ,PQR " numbers are missing

Comment: This is bad design, you should defiantly think about changing it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Ask a question, show us what you already tried, and what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

```
with table_name as
(
    select 'ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900' col_name from dual
)
select 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name,'#([^#,])*', null) alphabet_num
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name,'([^#,])*#', null) num_value
from 
    table_name;
```

Editted: Remove some redundant character as suggested by `MTO`

Comment: The regular expression `[^#,^\,]` will look for a single character that is not either `#`, `,`, `^`, `\ ` or `,` (again). I don't think it is doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for suggestion. Editted.

Comment: @VineetPalan You should update your query as my new answer

Comment: Yes..Pham and @MT0

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col VARCHAR2(100) );

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900' );

CREATE TYPE key_value_pair AS OBJECT(
  key   VARCHAR2(20),
  value NUMBER(10)
);
/

CREATE TYPE key_value_pair_table AS TABLE of key_value_pair;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.col, '(^|,)([^,#]+)#(\d+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2 ),
                    TO_NUMBER(
                      REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.col, '(^|,)([^,#]+)#(\d+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 3 )
                    )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.col, '(^|,)([^,#]+)#(\d+)' )
           )
           AS key_value_pair_table
         )
       );
```

**Output**:

```
COL                                 KEY     VALUE
----------------------------------- ------- -----
ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900 ABC 123 78800
ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900 XYZ      4666
ABC 123#78800,XYZ#4666,PQR 444#9900 PQR 444  9900
```